# Why is the TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' coming up?

Tags: python-2.7, compiler-errors

> Hello guys just encountered an error after running my final code and i was wondering what i have done wrong?

import re

def password():
    print ('Enter a password\n\nThe password must be more than 6 characters.\n')

```
while True:
    password = raw_input('Password: ')
    if 6 < len(password):
        break
    print ('The password must be more than 6 characters.\n')

password_scores = {0:'Very weak', 1:'Weak', 2:'Medium', 3:'Strong', 4:'Very strong'}
password_strength = dict.fromkeys(['has_upper', 'has_lower', 'has_num' , 'has_sym', False])
if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    password_strength['has_upper'] = True
if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    password_strength['has_lower'] = True
if re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
    password_strength['has_num'] = True
if re.search(list("[ !#$%&'()*+,-./[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]") , password):
    password_strength['has_sym'] = True

score = len([b for b in password_strength.values() if b])

print ('Password is %s' % password_scores[score])
```

password()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `if` statement with the following one and it will work:

```
if re.search("[!#$%&'()*+,-./[\\\]^_`{|}~ ]" , password):
    password_strength['has_sym'] = True
```